# Article (a or the) before a percentage? What is the rule?

Tags: grammar, articles, percentages

When can I use an article (the, a) when speaking of percentages? Are these examples correct? Is there a rule?

This represents 10% of the British population.

Twenty scholars collaborated in the study, representing **the** 10% of the association's members.

Only 10% of the members surveyed have young children, while **a** 90% have dedicated their life to elderly people care.

Between 1999 and 2002, 10% of the factories reduced carbon footprint and **a** 20% have launched environmental projects.

Comment: All of those articles are wrong.

Comment: Thank you Michael. How would you write the sentences then?

Comment: I would delete the articles.

Comment: You only use _the_ when describing the percentage in some way, e.g. 'Of _the_ 60% of members _who responded to the survey_, half said that...'.

Comment: *The* isn't necessarily wrong in the first example in the question, but it only works if you've already discussed a certain percentage and are now referring to it again. (Plus, at least stylistically, if you do that either *that* or *this* would be more common.) However, it doesn't seem likely that's the context here.